# Record Type - Rename and replace references or create new and update references

Tags: record-type

Need a bit of advice. We need to change the name of RecordType which is referenced in a ton of places (e.g. Profiles, Apex etc)

Which is best

1. Rename RecordType and update references
2. Create new Record Type and update references

Components in our org which reference record type:

- Apex Classes
- Case.assignmentRules
- Queue
- Record Type
- Permission Sets
- Profiles
- Case Workflow
- Email Template - soft references
- List Views - soft references
- Layouts - soft references

Comment: If you are using developerName in all your code then I suggest just rename the label not the developerName. if your are using name in code then i guess then you need to update all reference. that's why I always prefer to use developerName

Comment: Thanks Ratan. In a simple setup you can simply rename and the change cascades across most  things. We have a complex release process and many orgs which would require the change to be applied before finally reaching production. In Apex we are not referencing DeveloperName (before my time)